# HIVE : Hive authorization issues

Tags: authorization, hive

I try to set up authorisations on hive but i have some interogations... 
First i have turn on hive.security.authorization.enable

```
hive> set hive.security.authorization.enabled;
hive.security.authorization.enabled=true
```

when i check grant on default database for user hadoop_user i haven't any grant :

```
hive> show grant user hadoop_user on database default;
OK
Time taken: 1.278 seconds
```

But i can still create table on database :

```
hive> CREATE TABLE default.authorization_test(key int, value string);
OK
Time taken: 0.029 seconds
```

Can be my HDFS right... But when i change if, i can't do anything

```
hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - hive users          0 2013-07-26 10:50 /apps/hive/warehouse
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This will help you, check this: [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-authorization.html)

Comment: My problem should be solved if i add lines describes in "Configuration Parameters for Metastore Security" ?

Comment: This authorization scheme is valid for Hive release 0.10, so if you are using Hive 0.10 then it should work.